# SQL - combined SELECT queries and getting a % output

Tags: sql, select

I am using SQLiteStudio and I am trying to run the following query. However, it isn't returning a value. Can anyone help, please?

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(t_record.LocationID)
  FROM t_record,
       t_location
 WHERE t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID AND 
       Y_AXIS >= 0 AND 
       Goal_for = 1)
       /
(SELECT COUNT(GoalID)
  FROM t_record
 WHERE t_record.Goal_for)
* 100
```

I have been asked to provide some of the data. Below I have included how I created my 3 tables and then some sample data for each section. Hopefully, this is enough but feel free to ask for more.
These are the 3 tables I have created

```
CREATE TABLE t_location (
LocationID INT PRIMARY KEY,
X_Axis INT NOT NULL,
Y_AXIS INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE t_method (
MethodID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Body_Part VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE t_record (
    GoalID     INT                PRIMARY KEY,
    LocationID [INT FORIEIGN KEY] REFERENCES t_location (LocationID),
    MethodID   [INT FORIEIGN KEY] REFERENCES t_method (MethodID),
    Time       INT                NOT NULL,
    Goal_for   BOOLEAN            NOT NULL
```

Data for the method table

```
INSERT INTO t_method 
VALUES (1,'Left Foot');

INSERT INTO t_method 
VALUES (2,'Right Foot');

INSERT INTO t_method 
VALUES (3,'Head');
```

Data for the location table - only included 3 locations.

```
INSERT INTO t_location 
VALUES (1, 0, -1);

INSERT INTO t_location 
VALUES (2, 0, 0);

INSERT INTO t_location 
VALUES (3, 0, 1);
```

Data for the record table, it is very pland but I've varied the location.

```
INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (2, 1, 1, 6, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (3, 2, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (4, 2, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (5, 2, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (6, 2, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (7, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (8, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (9, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (10, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (11, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (12, 3, 1, 28, 1);

INSERT INTO t_record 
VALUES (1, 3, 1, 28, 1);
```

Thanks

Comment: First: stay away from implicit joins (`FROM a , b WHERE a.id=b.id`). This syntax is over 30 years old and deprecated, because it shouts for problems. Use: `FROM a JOIN b USING(id)`. Second: Can you provide a dozen rows for `location` and `record` by adding them to your question, adding three back-ticks (```) on one line before the data and again after the data, so we can play to create a solution?

Comment: Thanks, I've added some extra detail.

Comment: If you use a left join, you can simply divide the counts in a single query. It will also improve readability if you use table aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you had just a few syntax errors and correcting them plus adding something like * 1.0 to count() would do what you want (otherwise count() results are integer and in SQL server integer / integer would yield an integer which is 0 in your case).

This is your code, slightly modified to work:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(t_record.LocationID)
  FROM t_record,
       t_location
 WHERE t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID AND 
       Y_AXIS >= 0 AND 
       Goal_for = 1) * 1.0
       /
(SELECT COUNT(GoalID) 
  FROM t_record
 WHERE t_record.Goal_for=1)
* 100;
```

(I agree with preventing old style joins etc but was not the problem here).
You could make it a little better:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(t_record.LocationID)
  FROM t_record,
       t_location
 WHERE t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID AND 
       Y_AXIS >= 0 AND 
       Goal_for = 1) * 100.0
       /
(SELECT COUNT(GoalID) 
  FROM t_record
 WHERE t_record.Goal_for=1) as Pct;
```

While the above code works, I think there is a better and cleaner way:

```
SELECT SUM(case when Y_AXIS >= 0 then 1 end) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)
   FROM t_record
   inner join t_location ON t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID 
   where Goal_for = 1;
```

You can also check what is really going on there with adding those fields:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(case when Y_AXIS >= 0 then 1 end) as YAXIS_GTE_ZERO,
   COUNT(*) as Total,
   SUM(case when Y_AXIS >= 0 then 1 end) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) as Pct
   FROM t_record
   inner join t_location ON t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID 
   where Goal_for = 1;
```

And here is [DBFiddle demo using your example data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daa3befc856eaffa414c7b033fe12cbe)

EDIT: And this is for YAXIS >= 0 and YAXIS < 0 as in your comment:

```
SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS>=0 THEN 1 END)                   AS Opp_half_goals
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS<0 THEN 1 END)                    AS Own_half_goals
    , COUNT(*)                                              AS Total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS>=0 THEN 1 END)* 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS Opp_half_Pct
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS<0 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS Own_half_Pct
FROM  t_record
      INNER JOIN t_location ON t_record.LocationID=t_location.LocationID
WHERE Goal_for=1;
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you. Is there a way of limiting the % to 2 decimal places? Also, is there a way to show the other percentage of records from ,0 on the Y Axis?

Comment: That would be formatting, which depends on your backend.  And yes you can do it for other values as well on the same line creating additional fields using the same as above amd just changing the condition in case when.

Comment: Thanks, that working really well. I am trying to add records from <0 on YAXIS. I've managed to get the integer to display but can't get the %. Code is below, would be grateful for any hints.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS >= 0 THEN 1 END) AS Opp_half_goals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS < 0 THEN 1 END) AS Own_half_goals,
       COUNT( * ) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Y_AXIS >= 0 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT( * ) AS Opp_half_Pct
  FROM t_record
       INNER JOIN
       t_location ON t_record.LocationID = t_location.LocationID
 WHERE Goal_for = 1;

```

Comment: @MarkDennett, you were very close, you only forgot to add * 100.0 / Count(*) for that new sum() -YAXIS < 0. Edited to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this; using `1.0` instead of `1` in the `CASE WHEN` expression, to avoid an integer division by integer, which would have resulted in a truncated integer as the result, namely 0:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN y_axis >= 0 THEN 1.0 END)
  / COUNT(*)  
  * 100 
 AS result
FROM t_record
JOIN t_location USING(locationid)
;
-- out          result         
-- out ------------------------
-- out  84.6153846153846153800
```